# EclipseLink jpql "where clause" comparing timestamp is not working as expected

Tags: java, db2, eclipselink, jpql, weblogic12c

My jpql "where clause" that selects using a timestamp column does not "filter" as expected.

It appears sensitive to the "date" portion of the timestamp, but, ignores the "time" portion.

The table1.tmstmp column is defined as: "TMSTMP TIMESTAMP NOT NULL"

The table1 entity contains the following named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "table1.getUpdTime", query = "SELECT e FROM table1 e     
WHERE e.tmstmp >= :tmstmp order by e.tmstmp asc")
```

The tmstmp property is defined like this:

```
@Column(name = "TMSTMP", nullable = false)
private Timestamp tmstmp;
```

It is used like this:

```
TypedQuery<EsEvnt> query = em.createNamedQuery("table1.getUpdTime",
table1.class).setParameter("tmstmp", tmstmp);
```

For example, when the Timestamp variable ("tmstmp"), above, is equal to "2016-06-30T09:28:33.247-04:00", it returns all records where the date portion is:  2016-06-30.

Any ideas?

I'd like to depend upon the "where clause" to explicitly select using the entire timestamp.

### Update

I modified my query (seemed a native query was required) using the "CAST" function, as shown below, and it appears to work consistently:

```
//...note, date is in ISO format...
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(tmstmpString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
Timestamp tmstmp = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt);
- 
-
-
// (see "native query", coded below)...
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM table1 e WHERE e.tmstmp >= CAST(?1 as TIMESTAMP)", Table1.class)  
        .setParameter(1, tmstmp);  
List<Table1> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

---

WebLogic 12.1.3

DB2

Java 8

EclipseLink 2.1

Comment: And the `tmstmp` field is indeed a `Timestamp`? As `java.sql.Date` sets hour, minutes and seconds to 0.

Comment: Yes,  "tmstmp" is type: Timestamp.  thx for asking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below, is what worked for me...

Assuming...

```
    //...note, date is in ISO format...
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(tmstmpString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
    Timestamp tmstmp = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt);
```

Here's one way...

```
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM table1 e WHERE e.tmstmp >= CAST(?1 as TIMESTAMP)", Table1.class)  
            .setParameter(1, tmstmp);  
    List<Table1> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Here's another way...

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Table1> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Table1.class);
    Root<Table1> table1 = criteriaQuery.from(Table1.class);

    Expression<Byte> expression = table1.get("tmstmp"); // ...NOTE: column name is "tmstmp"...
    Expression<Timestamp> castFunction = criteriaBuilder.function("TIMESTAMP", Timestamp.class, expression);
    Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(castFunction, tmstmp);

    //NOTE: should be able to add to predicate...
    //      e.g.,   
    //          predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, otherPredicate);

    criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
    TypedQuery<Table1> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    List<Table1> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you?

```
query.setParameter("tmstmp", tmstmp, TemporalType.DATE)
```

UPDATE:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "TMSTMP", nullable = false)
private Date tmstmp;
```

Comment: No that does not work.    -I had tried that and  "TemporalType.TIMESTAMP", too... -But, to no avail. Thx